# what is the visual feedback in parkinson's disease?

Tags: neurology

the patient cannot walk normally, but can only walk if there are black and white squares on the floor. How can we explain this visual feedback physiologically? basically what is visual feedback? What are the resource books on this subject?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: thanks for helpful resources is really helpful but ı but I could not find the answer to my question I hope more specific sources will be suggested

Comment: We don't ask that you find the answer. We only ask that you put forth a little effort and tell us what you found. If you found nothing, what did you search? For example, by entering `Parkinson's squares on floor` in google I found [this](https://academic.oup.com/brain/article/122/1/111/330308) right away. I'm sure there's more

Comment: I met this site 3 days ago, but I have been looking for the answer to this question for about 2 months and have read many articles like this and mostly confirms the effects of lines or squares on the ground in Parkinson's patients and hypotheses are suggested, but I could not find an EEG or fMR study to test the accuracy of these hypotheses. . In asking the question here, my goal was to get him to help me if there was an article or something I missed, rather than finding a precise correct answer. thank you for your time